# How to create a hello world button in java

Tags: java, swing, button, graphics

**I am  trying to make a button that says hello world but it dose not work I tried multiple times but nothing i did made a difference**

```
[![package com.company;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    public class Main implements ActionListener {
        JButton b;
        JFrame f;
        public Main()
        {
            b=new JButton("hello");
            b.addActionListener(this);
            b.setBounds(100,100,95,30);
            f.setTitle("first");
            f.setSize(500,300);
            f.add(b);
            f.setVisible(true);
            f.setLayout(null);
        }
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource()==b)
            {
                System.out.print("hello world");
            }
        }
        public static void main(String\[\] args) {
            // write your code here
            new Main();
        }

    }][1]][1]
```

**and this is he result it displays**

Answer (score 3):

You need to instantiate your `JFrame` in the constructor with `f = new JFrame();`.